# Why is baseDN incorrect when doing ldapTemplate.authenticate()?

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to authenticate against active directory using Spring's LDAP package, but I keep getting an error saying that I have specified the wrong baseDN (Ldap error code 32):

```
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E4, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
   [testng]     'OU=People,DC=example,DC=com'
   [testng] ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E4, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
   [testng]     'OU=People,DC=example,DC=com'
   [testng] ]; remaining name 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com'
```

The strange thing is that the ldapsearch command uses the exact basedn, and it works:

```
ldapsearch -V -x -H ldap://ad.example.com:389 -b 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' -D '<user>' -w '<password>' (sAMAccountName=<user>)
```

The following code sets the DN (the ldapContextSource is set programmatically):

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", user));
DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName("ou=people,dc=example,dc=com");
boolean in = ldapTemplate.authenticate(dn, filter.toString(), password);
```

Not sure if this will help, but these are the other fields:

```
userDN = <myusername>@example.com
url = ldap://ad.example.com:389
password = <mypassword>
baseDN = ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

**EDIT**: I changed the userDN: cn=username,out=people,dc=example,dc=com
This still gives error 32 code.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks guys, your clues did indeed shed light on the problem.

First, the userDN was indeed incorrect. I fixed that (see edit in original post).

Second, since I had already specified the baseDN in the ldapContextSource, there is no need to do it again when calling the authenticate(). So using `DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH` solved that problem.

Third, my equals filter was incorrect. When I changed the userDN, I forgot that `sAMAccountName` needed to be changed to the actual login name, and not the userDN as it was originally set to.

The ldapTemplate.authenticate() now returns true, which means I've authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a base DN problem. I think the user was not found. Are you setting the search scope correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure. If I say that the userDN = <myusername>, then I would get this error:  `LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525`, which means that the user is not found. So since I didn't get that error, I just assumed that my userDN was found.

Comment: You might be right though. The userDN looks suspiciously wrong, but what confuses me is why I don't get the AcceptSecurityContext exception then?

Comment: @user1812844 It is the purpose of the filter to *find* the user whose samAccountName equals whatever is in 'user'. Is there such a user?

Comment: Yes, for now I just want to query myself. So what happens is I authenticate, then do a search for my username.

Answer (score 1):

Your userDN looks suspicious.  DN should look like cn='username',ou='rest of path',dc=example,dc=com.  I don't see its use in your code, only user.  user should be 'username'.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it. I still receive the same error (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

The base object in a search (the value of the `-b` argument) is different from the distinguished name used in the simple bind (`-D` argument). Result code `32` (in the search response) means that the base object (in the search request) was not found.

#### see also

- [LDAP: search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)